# Ubuntu download ISO for my computer?

Tags: iso

From Ubuntu I download

ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

But I don't see AMD in my motherboard of my computer

Which iso from Ubuntu site, I have to download for my computer?

[ECS _ P4M800PRO-M (V1.0A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpU0O.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question

AMD64 just means 64bit so get that one if you have a 64 bit CPU. Most CPUs are 64bit these days.

Here is a link that might help explain.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Ben

Edit:  that chipset does not have support for 64 bit so the alternative would be the 32 bit equivalent iso or also known as i386x in the iso name.